# General strategies for understanding a given group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that there is no general algorithm for determining what familiar group (if any) a given presentation represents; even the problem of determining if a presentation represents the trivial group is undecidable.

However, when looking at a presentation, what are some good strategies for trying to discover truths about the group it represents? What kinds of approaches are often helpful in determining the order of a group, whether it is abelian, what kinds of subgroups it might possess, whether any of the listed generators are redundant, etc?

Comment: This is kinda a broad question. Are you doing something that is generating group presentations that you need to know more about? Are you just preparing for some kind of exam questions like "what familiar group is this?"  The first thing I would look at when deciding what group a presentation represents is look at where the presentation came from.

Comment: I realize the question is kind of broad, but I'm having a hard time thinking of how to narrow it down. I'm really encountering group presentations for the first time and learning how to work with them, so I'm working on a lot of problems where I'm just given presentations and asked to show what familiar group it is, or show that it is nonabelian or has certain order, etc. I'm just often at a loss of where to even begin with these kinds of problems and wondering about general strategies for tackling these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to look at where the group came from. Outside of pure group theory, groups *act* on objects, and this is a big hint as to what the group is. It could be a group of symmetries of a geometric object, or a group of automorphisms of a space or a field. Often times, especially when dealing with free groups or things close to free groups (not too many relations), it helps to view the group as the fundamental group of a covering space, just so you can have a picture for the group.

But since it sounds like you are just working with groups for the sake of groups, here are a few tips:

- Just start playing with the generators and relations to write down as many elements of the group as you can. Early on while learning group theory, the *familiar* groups are almost all finite. So you might just be able to write down every element.
- Play with just the relations to see what becomes trivial in the group.

  - If you can generate one of the generators from the relations, that means that generator is redundant.
  - If you generate a string $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, that means those elements $a$ and $b$ commute.
  - And there are a few common relations to look for. Like if you get the relations $a^n, b^2, (ab)^2$, there's a dihedral-like part of your group. Wikipedia has a list of other [common relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Common_examples), like those present in the symmetric group or in braid groups.

If you want something more formal, you can always check out [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations).

Answer (score 1):

A good strategy is to apply the [Todd-Coxeter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm).